# SQL Server & C# UTF8 encoding not correct

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding

I am getting a very big file from a linux box which I import with TOAD Wizard to SQL Server Express for testing

The file is supposed to be correctly using special characters like ÄäÖö... which the admin of the box confirms.

I am seeing only misinterpreted characters (like Ã„) via Putty&less, textviewer in windows, toads import wizard, inside the db and when returning the values in .net

The only idea I have is to replace the characters in C# but for that I would need a complete list of replacements to do.

Does anyone have such a list, a finished class or any other idea?

Comment: Do you see the proper characters if you open the file with notepad++ on the Windows Box?

Comment: Its too big for Notepadd++, in LTFviewer the files are corrupt (after copying via scp from linux box)

Comment: It looks like you are importing the file with different encoding than it actually has. What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: If the file is corrupt you should try to copy the file in a way that does not corrput it? How big are they? Can't the be splitted?

Comment: linux says "UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines" and I copy it with winscp to my machine and import that with TOADs import Wizard as Unicode (UTF-8) ... at the moment I try to help myself with replacing the wrong characters in code ...

Comment: Consider how likely it is that you are the first person in the world to discover that .NET UTF8 encoding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by converting the file on the unix side:

[iconv unicode unknown input format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688464/iconv-unicode-unknow-input-format)

**use iconv to upconvert UTF-8 to UTF-16**, which SQLServer can import correctly