# iconv unicode unknown input format

Tags: unix, encoding, utf-8

I have a file which is described under Unix as:

```
$file xxx.csv 
xxx.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Viewing it in `less`/`vi` will render some special chars (ßÄ°...) unreadable (├╝); Windows will also not display it; importing it directly into a db will just change the special characters to some other special characters (+ä, +ñ, ...).

I wanted to convert it now to a "default readable" encoding with iconv.
When I try to convert it with iconv

```
$iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 xxx.csv > yyy.csv
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1234
```

using UNICODE as input and UTF-8 as output will return the same message

I am guessing the file is somewhat encoded in another format which I do not know - how can I find out which format in order to convert it to something "universally" readable  ...

Comment: Try opening it in a text editor that allows you to change the encoding with which to open the file. Worst case a browser will do as well. Then play around with the available encodings and see what displays characters correctly.

Comment: I tried with notepad++ but it is 680MB and notepad++ tells me it is too big ..

Comment: The file is obviously not UTF-8, even if `file` guessed it. Can you show us the eight bytes starting at offset 1234, in their hexdump form?

Comment: How would I do that? Btw I opened it on my mac with bbedit which opens it correcly rendered as unicode utf-8 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that Windows could not interpret the file as UTF-8 on itself. it reads it as asci and then ä becomes a 2 character interpretation Ã¤ (ascii 195 164)

trying to convert it, I found a solution that works for me:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252//TRANSLIT --output=outfile.csv inputfile.csv
```

now I can view the special chars correctly in editors

For SQLServer compability, converting UTF-8 to UTF-16 will work even better ... just the filesize grows quite a bit

Answer (score 16):

Converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 only works if your UTF-8 text only has characters that can be represented in ISO-8859-1. If this is not the case, you should specify what needs to happen to these characters, either ignoring (//IGNORE) or approximating (//TRANSLIT) them. Try one of these two:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//IGNORE --output=outfile.csv inputfile.csv
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT --output=outfile.csv inputfile.csv
```

In most cases, I guess approximation is the best solution, mapping e.g. accented characters to their unaccented counterparts, the euro sign to EUR, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about the file type you dealing with then you can find it as follows,

```
file file_name
```

The above command will give you the file format. Then **iconv** can be used accordingly.
For example if the file format is **UTF-16** and you want to convert it to **UTF-8** then following can be used.

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 file_name >output_file_name
```

Hope this gives add on insight to what you are looking for.